# xtext to xtend and xtend to xtext transformation

Tags: eclipse, xtext, xtend

Good day,

I am working on an xtext project. I have written xtend to transform "runtime DSL instance" into equivalent code (text file).

Now I want that when I change the generated code (text file) the same is reflected in the "runtime DSL instance"

Any guidelines please .... ?

Comment: can you please rephrase / explain what you mean by "the same is reflected in the "runtime DSL instance""

Comment: if you mean transforming java or c++ or whatever code you generate back to dsl code, there is nothing ootb and you need to build that yourself

Comment: Yes, I exactly meant back and fro transformation. I need a starting point to do so. Is there any tutorial available?

Comment: no. you basically need to parse the generated file and then do a m2m on the source file or a text generation to it. what kind of file is the generated file? is there a specific reason you want to transform back?

Comment: Im doing it for research purposes. For the time being, im generating .txt file but in future I need to work on Uppaal and other files.  Please guide me where to parse the generated file ? The scenario is I need the backwards transformation in real time, please suggest..

Comment: Im trying it on very simple one line grammar. My DSL allows to write "Hello" or "Goodbye". In doGenerate I convert "Hello" to "Hi" and "Goodbye" to "Bye" in a new text file. Now I want if user wants to update the text file and update "Bye" to "Goodbye" then it must be updated in the DSL Runtime instance. Please guide.

Comment: i fear this one you need to do manually yourself.

Comment: what is the exact problem you are stuck to get started with this?

Comment: For dsl to code: I write the logic in (yourdsl)Generator.xtend. Here, I get the runtime instance in doGenerate() and generate the desired code. In runtime instance, the code is generated when I press save button.

Comment: Now for code to dsl: I am unable to get the generated code instance? Im also unable to figure it out that would this translation be done on save button?

Comment: I can read the generated file in ..Generator.xtend as : System.out.println(fsa.readTextFile("MyZModel.txt")); .......... after this I'm stuck...

Comment: this part is not replated to Xtext but rather to eclipse itself. so you need to hook into the manual save of the generated file. this can  be done in the editor impl (depending on what file you really generate outside art. usecase) or by writing a custom builder. ps: i still have severe doubts that your usecase is the way to go. am not sure if there is a better pattern to solve your actual problem. but therefore i need to get a better picture of the actual usecase.